# Is there a way to filter out partial matches from search results on YouTube?

Tags: youtube

When searching for “JoJo's Bizarre Adventure,” I frequently just search the keyword “jojo,” but my first sight is often greeted by a musical artist by the same name.

Instead, I'd prefer that all my YouTube results not show a single result pertaining to the artist, and instead pertaining to the anime itself.

Is there a way to a filter out specific content from the search results?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue; have you tried including the quotation marks in your YouTube search? you may also have more luck just going to google and searching `"JoJo's Bizarre Adventure" site:youtube.com`.

Comment: Using the keyword `jojo`, it brings up the first result as the musical artist, whereas a few listings down is jojo's bizarre adventure stuff.

Comment: any reason why not use YT search' autocomplete and search directly the full phrase > `jojo bizarre adventure` ? just type `jojo` and press arrow down

Comment: 4 characters is a lot simpler than doing all that complicated stuff

Comment: lol. indeed 4 clicks for `jojo` is less than 5 clicks for `jojo`+`arrow down`

Comment: You forget that mobile users can't use "arrow down".